# Ruby Tiny_tds: nText columntype gets truncated to 32223

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, tiny-tds

I am using these gems

```
ruby-odbc (0.99995)
tiny_tds (0.6.2)
```

and making Tiny TDS connection like this

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => myusernmae, :password => mypassword, :dataserver => 'UKRCAN')
result = client.execute("SELECT C FROM [dbo].[Feedback] f where FeedBackId = 'DD0F1A3E-0499-401A-A4E9-7F2EC6564C52'")
```

Where C column is of type nText

The issue is when I try to fetch nText column (which has characters somewhere around  1,00,000), gets truncated in result to 32223 characters only.

Any suggestions on how can I get the complete value of this column

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by setting the MSSQL configuration

```
result = client.execute("SET TEXTSIZE 1073741823")
result.do
```